# Are the two different Forms of the damped pseudo-inverse (damped Moore–Penrose inverse) equal?

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse, matrix-equations, singularity, pseudoinverse

To generalize the concept of the inverse to non square matrix the pseudo inverse (also called [Moore–Penrose inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse)) can be used:

For tall matrices with full column rank:
$$A^+ = (A^T \cdot A)^{-1} A^T$$

For wide matrices with full row rank:
$$A^+ =  A^T(A \cdot A^T)^{-1}$$

If A has not full rank(row or column) and is therefore singular the inverse of in the above equation is not defined anymore. To arrive at the damped Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse we can therefore introduce a damping term into the two equations above to make sure the inverse is defined
$$A_d^+ = (A^T \cdot A + \lambda^2     \mathbb{I})^{-1} A^T$$
$$A_d^+ =  A^T(A \cdot A^T + \lambda^2     \mathbb{I})^{-1}$$

Are the two formulas above equal for equal lambda and a general real matrix A? After trying out several examples it seems to me that this could be the case. If it is true, how would you formally proof this?
$$A_d^+ = (A^T \cdot A + \lambda^2     \mathbb{I})^{-1} A^T= A^T(A \cdot A^T + \lambda^2     \mathbb{I})^{-1}$$

Comment: The equality is obvious if you use singular value decomposition. However, the two expressions are *not* the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse of $A$. It is true, however, that their limits (as $\lambda\to0$) are equal to $A^+$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, the two later expressions of course refer to the damped Moore Penrose Pseudoinverse and not the standart Moore Penrose Inverse (That is the name i found in the literature for this form). I adapted the question to make this a bit more clear.